# Ruby - STDIN with getc()

Tags: ruby, stdin

I am trying save the input from the command prompt into an array. The input will be integers and the first number will be the total number of characters that follow. An example input would look like:

```
     10
     5
     3
     8 2 1
     8 9
     4 6
     7
```

I can't seem to find a way to be able to save each number to an array. `gets.chomp` takes the entire line as a value, making it difficult to save each number to the array itself. I tried working around it with `line.split` but then the first integer would throw off my for loop and put a load of `0`'s at the end of the array.

Does Ruby have the functionality to read each character by itself? I know Java has the `.nextInt()` function in the `Scanner` class. Also, I am new to Stack Overflow and coding in general, please be frank on how I can better communicate my question and how to code in general.

My current code reads as :

```
      a = Float(gets.chomp)
      x=[]
      for i in 0..a do
        currentNum = Float(gets.chomp)
        x.push(currentNum)
      end
      puts x
```

Comment: The sample input you've provided has one number per line, so my instinct goes to `gets.chomp`. What's wrong with taking "the entire line as a value", as you say? I don't fully understand that bit.

Comment: `a, *x = ARGF.read.split.map(&:to_i)`?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo - the example input's third line has three individual numbers on it; 8, 2, and 1.

Comment: @StefanPochmann - Where do you suggest to place that code?

Comment: @Abram Not sure what you mean. Into a file? Where do you have your code now?

Comment: @StefanPochmann - Haha. I mean what part of the file, I can't seem to get it to work. I've place `a, *x = ARGF.read.split.map(&:to_i)` before the `for` loop. The program simply accepts input from the command prompt forever.

Comment: Not somewhere in that code of yours. It's supposed to replace all of that code of yours. Demo: https://ideone.com/R7zqTi